# Invoke a date picker instead of a standard keyboard

Tags: iphone, date, textfield, picker

I need to invoke a UIDatePicker when i tap on a textfield. Usually when we tap on a textfield the keyboard pops up. But I need a date picker instead of that. Can anyone help me please...!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UIDatePicker returns NSDdate. Use NSDateFormatter to get the string you want:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [format stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A textfield is a control you use for text input. This is why tapping on it the keyboard pops up. If you need a date picker, simply use directly a date picker if you have space in your view, otherwise use a button and set the target-action of the button so that it shows a new view containing your date picker.

Comment: Thanks... i implemented a button for that.. can you please tell me how to remove the time from the string which i get from the date picker. I just need the date.

Thanks